# Statusbar should remain in its place when keyboard is shown

Tags: java, android, xml

In whatsApp or google messenger the statusbar don't slide up on keyboard shown and `ListView`resizes according to `Edittext`. I have set the `AdjustResize` property in `android:windowSoftInputMode` according to some research in stackoverflow. That property resizes the `ListView` but also slides the statusbar up. I want the persistent statusbar. I have also tried `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` but no use. I am using support `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar` and `AppCompactActivity` with `Theme.AppCompact.Light.NoActionBar` theme.

**manifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.ConversationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**chat.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_conversation"
tools:context=".activities.ConversationActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tb_conversation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_conversation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_doctor"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/img_doctor"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <com.views.CircularNetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_doctor"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tab_profile" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tb_conversation"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAppGray" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view2"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/input_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAppGray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_msgInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_send_image"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_send_image"
            android:background="@drawable/res_bg_conversation_et"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/btn_send_image"
            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/btn_send_image"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingTop="18dp"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_send_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_send_msg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/et_msgInput"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/et_msgInput"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Gonder"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**code.java**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_conversation);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**Images**

First look

[image: First]

After clicking on the `Edittext` Keyboard is shown

Expected(Statusbar remains in it's place)

[image: Expected]

Happening(Statusbar is sliding out of the view) :(

[image: Happening]

Comment: @J.Chomel code added.. please review

Comment: Now we have something to chew on, thanks Bilal!

Comment: Thanks to you too for giving me that precious suggestion. Now my question is more towards the solution. :)

Comment: Your question is quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283546/how-to-change-my-chat-layout-output-as-like-whatsapp-chat-layout?rq=1 . have you tried its solution?

Comment: Could you post some image or demo video about your behavior? Cause I've tried your code, and there are no problems with status bar.

Comment: Images added for more detail @rom4ek

Comment: @J.Chomel. That's not my question. kindly see images for proper understanding.

Comment: Firstly, I understand your problem, I need exactly the screens from the app, cause wireframes don't give us the imagination. Secondly, we need probably code of your activity, full manifest and styles to see what can be wrong.

Comment: Hey @BilalHaiderMakki I've put all your code and it seems working for me, what I've to remove is <com.views.CircularNetworkImageView from because I don't have that class. Check over here : http://postimg.org/image/cepdgc0uj/

Comment: @Bilal Haider Makki, what is the best answer now? Could you accept the best? I know not this technique but I'd like to award the bounty to the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. Issue was not with the `AdjustResize` or `AdjustPan`. It was with the `Activity` to be fullscreen. In fullscreen `Activity` the adjusting mechanism of keyboard does not work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Use my below code to change in manifest.xml

```
 <activity
  android:name=".activities.ConversationActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Also you can change dynamically in java file

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    super.onPause();
}
```

I also suggest to use fragment like below images.

[image]

Comment: @Elesh, do you know why Bilal's issue isn't solved yet? I would like to know this before I award the bounty.

Comment: Ok we did what we could for Bilal. Thanks Elesh!

Answer (score 2):

Try without adding windowSoftinput mode

```
<activity 
    android:name="com.app.name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    />
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
<activity 
    android:name="com.app.name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: why `stateVisible`? I don't want to show keyboard in the start of the activity so couldn't use `stateVisible`. And i tried with adjustPan already. didn't solved it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Chitrang's solution.

He  has put all your code and it seems working for him, just by removing  `<com.views.CircularNetworkImageView` because that class doesn't exist.

Check over here : http://postimg.org/image/cepdgc0uj/

Comment: @Bilal Haider Makki, have you tried Chitrang's solution?

Comment: @JChomel yeah tried it. no use. i have tried all the solutions that are given here. :( i think it's the issue with the theme. what do you say?

Comment: Well I know nothing about it :) I was just trying to help a newcomer by attracting more attention... You should comment each answer if possible, so that people get notified and try to improve their answers.